# How to prevent in a library updating file contents but allow changing of meta data?

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, modified

Assuming a library named *Assets* which contains stuff like PNG, JPEG, PDF, ...

1. We want to **allow** to **all** people:

   1. List all folder and files (assets)
   2. See meta information (columns) of all files and folder
2. We want to **allow** to **specific** people:

   1. Add new assets
   2. Changes of meta information (columns) like *Title*, *Custom Column1*, *Custom Column2*, ...
3. But we want to **forbid** to **all** people:

   1. Change the file content of already existing files/assets.

How we can achieve that in SharePoint of an Office 365 tenant?

Answer (score 0):

By default in SharePoint if you have permissions to edit the metadata you are going to have permissions to edit the file that the metadata is attached to.  The metadata and the file are not separate "objects" that you can set different permissions on.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. This is something what I'm already aware of. But I'm looking for an altnative way. For example using a trigger or whatever...

Answer (score 0):

You can do a *hacky* solution and employ Record Labels for this purpose. By applying a record label to the files, they will become uneditable. However, there is a tenant-wide setting for allowing/disallowing editing of metadata on records that will let you edit metadata. Users with container admin privileges will be able to Remove the record label and update the content.